# Prolog Family Tree, cousins issues

Tags: prolog

I am trying to list all the cousins of a particular person in my prolog program but can't seem to get it to work. I've checked my code and it seems correct but I am not getting the output I want.

```
father(john, johnny).
father(john, peter).
father(josh, william).
father(simone, betty).

mother(mary, johnny).
mother(mary, peter).
mother(catherine, william).
mother(kate, betty).

parent(A,B) :- father(A,B).
parent(A,B) :- mother(A,B).

siblings(B,G) :- parent(P,B), parent(P,G), B\=G.
cousins(X,Y) :- parent(A,X), parent(B,Y), siblings(A,B), X\=Y.
```

I want when I query `cousins(X, william).` to return the 2 cousins but I am only getting false as a return. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: heres what I have now, but can only get 1 cousin to display

```html
father(grandpa1, mary).
father(grandpa1, catherine).
father(grandpa2, john).
father(grandpa2, simone).
father(john, johnny).
father(john, peter).
father(josh, william).
father(simone, betty).

mother(grandma1, mary).
mother(grandma1, catherine).
mother(grandma2, john).
mother(grandma2, simone).
mother(mary, johnny).
mother(mary, peter).
mother(catherine, william).
mother(kate, betty).

parent(A,B) :- father(A,B).
parent(A,B) :- mother(A,B).

siblings(B,G) :- parent(P,B), parent(P,G), B\=G.
cousins(X,Y) :- parent(A,X), parent(B,Y), siblings(A,B), X\=Y.
```

Comment: Just a small comment. Prolog never returns anything, so you never get `false` returned. Goals/predicates either succeed or fail, that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a picture of your database

[image]

that shows there are no cousins, just because there are no relations among parents. Let's add an unknown, but shared, grandparent:

[image]

```
?- forall(cousins(X,william),writeln(X)).
johnny
peter
betty
```

If you're interested, the graphical representation can be obtained from this [github repo](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/tree/master/genealogy), with this minimal 'glue' code:

```
parent_child(P,C) :- parent(P,C).
```

Comment: I have added some additional unknown parents but I am still not getting the desired results, here was I added (an unknown father and mother for the parents):

father(uk1f, mary).
father(uk1f, catherine).
father(uk2f, john).
father(uk2f, simone).
mother(uk1m, mary).
mother(uk1m, catherine).
mother(uk2f, john).
mother(uk2f, simone).

I am only getting one cousin per query now instead of the 2. cousins(S,johnny). only returns betty, am I querying it wrong? Thanks for the help so far